# Django: Saving foreign key

Tags: django

I'm new in Django, From the Models below i don't want to let user choose the customer, but i want to save the customer_id in Fleet Model. How can i do that?

Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Fleet(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fleet_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Forms

```
 class FleetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Fleet
        fields = ['fleet_name']
```

View (I tried this but it's not working)

```
def fleet(request, customer_id):
    customer_record = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
    if request.method == "POST":    
        form = FleetForm(request.POST,instance=customer_record )
        if form.is_valid():
           fleet_record= form.save(commit=False)
           fleet_record.customer = customer_record
           fleet_record.save()
```

Urls

```
url(r'^fleet/(?P<customer_id>\d+)$', fleet, name='fleet')
```

Template

```
{% url 'fleet' customer_id %}
```

Comment: Well how do you determine the `customer_id`? Can you show the current view?

Comment: I added the view

Comment: The `,instance=customer_record` in the `FleetForm(..)`  call does not make much sense, since your model is about a `Fleet`, so that should be removed.

Comment: I removed it, but now i get this error NoReverseMatch at /view_fleet:  Reverse for 'fleet' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['fleet/(?P<customer_id>\\d+)$']

Comment: added urls and template above

Comment: Hi! @WillemVanOnsem